# Trying to append to list while using multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I've started using Python and Netmiko to connect to Cisco devices and scrape CLI commands into data. This is working great, but I need to bring down the time scripts take to complete when there is a large number of devices.

I can get multiprocessing to work as long as I just print out the output in the function I'm using. But when I try to use a shared list with multiprocessing, it fails.

For this example, I am generating a list of dictionaries called "device_list" in what I call "devices.py":

```
device_list = []
ip = 211

for x in range(5):
    device_list.append({'host': '192.168.0.' + str(ip),
                       'username': 'myusername',
                       'password': 'mypassword',
                       'device_type': 'cisco_ios'})
    ip = ip + 1
```

This list of dictionaries will be used by the Netmiko module to connect to the devices in my test lab.

Here is the main program:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from time import time
from netmiko import Netmiko
from devices import device_list

def connect_to_dev(output, **device):
    net_connect = Netmiko(**device)
    show_ver = net_connect.send_command('show version', use_textfsm = True)
    net_connect.disconnect()
    hostname = show_ver[0]['hostname']
    image = show_ver[0]['running_image'][28:62]
    result = '{}\nHostname: {}, version {}'.format(line, hostname, image)
    output.append(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    line = '*'*70
    start = time()
    mgr = mp.Manager()
    output = mgr.list()
    processes = []

    for device in device_list:
        p = mp.Process(target=connect_to_dev, args=output, kwargs=device)
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    end = time()
    runtime = round((end - start), 2)
    print(output)
    print('{}\nTime elapsed: {} seconds\n{}'.format(line, runtime, line))
```

I am trying to get each "result" generated by the "connect_to_dev" function appended to the "output" list. I'm getting this error:

```
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: connect_to_dev() missing 1 required positional argument: 'output'
Process Process-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
Process Process-5:
TypeError: connect_to_dev() missing 1 required positional argument: 'output'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: connect_to_dev() missing 1 required positional argument: 'output'
Process Process-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: connect_to_dev() missing 1 required positional argument: 'output'
Process Process-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: connect_to_dev() missing 1 required positional argument: 'output'
[]
**********************************************************************
Time elapsed: 0.05 seconds
**********************************************************************
```

Comment: change `args=output` to be `args=(output,)`

Comment: That's amazing! That solved it. Thank you so much!